# Manually inject model relation using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How can I add a model into the relations array of another model?

E.g.

- Domain belongsTo Owner.
- Owner hasOne Domain.
- I have $domain (instance of Domain).
- I have $owner (instance of Owner).

I want to add `$domain` to `$owner->relations[]` so that I can just use `$owner->domain` later on in my code.

The reason for doing this is such that in one particular controller i only need a partial data set from each model so use fluent to query with a join for performance reasons then fill the models.

Then for readability's sake I'd like to use `$owner->domain->id` etc

`$domain->owner()->associate($owner);` gives me a `$domain->owner` option

But then I can't work out the opposite version

```
$owner->domain()->associate($domain)
$owner->domain()->attach($domain)
```

both result in the following fatal error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::[attach|associate] ()

*NB: I don't want to save anything as I've already loaded all the data i need.*

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[setRelation()](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_setRelation) should work. It sets the value in the [relations](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#property_relations) array.

```php
$owner->setRelation('domain', $domain);
```

When setting a one to many relationship, you may need to use [values()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-values):

```php
$owner->setRelation('domains', $domains->values());
```